# appending Dict to nested list per request made

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am currently scraping through an XML API response. I am looking to gather a piece of information for each request and create a dictionary each time I find this piece of data. Each request can have several IDs. So one response can have 2 IDs while the next response might have 3 IDs. For example, let's say the first response has 2 IDs. I am storing this data in a list at the moment when the second request is done the additional 3 IDs are being stored under this same list as well.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime as datetime
import json
import time


trackingDomain = ''
domain = ''
aIDs = []
cIDs = []
url = "https://" + domain + ""


print(url)

df = pd.read_csv('campids.csv')
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    payload = {'api_key':'',
                'campaign_id':'0',
                'site_offer_id':row['IDs'],
                'source_affiliate_id':'0',
                'channel_id':'0',
                'account_status_id':'0',
                'media_type_id':'0',
                'start_at_row':'0',
                'row_limit':'0',
                'sort_field':'campaign_id',
                'sort_descending':'TRUE'
            }
    print('Campaign Payload', payload)
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    print(r.status_code)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    success = soup.find('success').string
    for affIDs in soup.select('campaign'):
        affID = affIDs.find('source_affiliate_id').string
        aIDs.append(affID)
        dataDict = dict()
        dataDict['offers'] = []
        affDict = {'affliate_id':aIDs}
        dataDict['offers'].append(dict(affDict))
```

The result ends up being as follows:

```
dictData = {'offers': [{'affliate_id': ['9','2','45','47','14','8','30','30','2','2','9','2']}]}
```

What I am looking to do is this:

```
dictData = {'offers':[{'affiliate_id'['9','2','45','47','14','8','30','30','2','2']},{'affiliate_id':['9','2']}]}
```

On the first request, I obtain the following:

```
IDs['9','2','45','47','14','8','30','30','2','2']
```

On the second request these IDs are returned:

```
['9','2']
```

I am new to Python so please bear with me as far etiquette goes and I am missing something. I'll be happy to provide any additional information.

Comment: Can you provide one of the urls as an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the order of your initializing and appending that is causing you to not get the outcome you are wanting. You are overwriting your `dataDict` after each iteration, and inserting the appended list which is not overwritten, thus leaving you with a final list that has appended ALL `aIDs`. What you want to to do is initialise that `dataDict` out side of your for loop, and then you can append the dictionary in the nested loop into that list:

**Note: It's tough to work out/test without having the actual data, but I believe this should do it if I worked out the logic correctly in my head:**

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime as datetime
import json
import time


trackingDomain = ''
domain = ''

cIDs = []
url = "https://" + domain + ""

# Initialize your dictionary
dataDict = dict()

# Initialize your list in your dictionary under key `offers`
dataDict['offers'] = []

print(url)

df = pd.read_csv('campids.csv')
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    payload = {'api_key':'',
                'campaign_id':'0',
                'site_offer_id':row['IDs'],
                'source_affiliate_id':'0',
                'channel_id':'0',
                'account_status_id':'0',
                'media_type_id':'0',
                'start_at_row':'0',
                'row_limit':'0',
                'sort_field':'campaign_id',
                'sort_descending':'TRUE'
            }
    print('Campaign Payload', payload)
    r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
    print(r.status_code)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    success = soup.find('success').string

    # Initialize your list for this iteration/row in your df.iterrows
    aIDs = []
    for affIDs in soup.select('campaign'):
        affID = affIDs.find('source_affiliate_id').string

        # Append those affIDs to the aIDs list
        aIDs.append(affID)

    # Create your dictionary of key:value with key 'affiliate_id' and value the aIDs list
    affDict = {'affliate_id':aIDs}

    # NOW append that into your list in your dictionary under key `offers`
    dataDict['offers'].append(dict(affDict))
```

Comment: Thank you, chitown88. this did the trick! Feel embarrassed by this but it was a good learning experience

Comment: @Aldo, Don't be embarrassed! It's all part of learning (just over a year ago I would have had no clue how to answer this question).